# ArrayList is not being populated

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I'm a bit of a Java noob, so any help is appreciated. I have a method that is supposed to take a char value and an Arraylist of words in alphabetical order, and return all of the strings in the list that start with the same letter as the char. I'm not getting any error messages, but my method keeps returning an empty ArrayList. Why isn't my List being filled?

```
 public String singlePhrase(char c, ArrayList<String> wordList){

  ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();      
  for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) { 
     if (wordList.get(i).charAt(0) == c){
        words.add(wordList.get(i));
     }
  }

  return "Size: "+words.size() + " "+c;             
}
```

Comment: Give example of the values in your `wordList`. For which value you are trying??

Comment: I assume none of your wordList words start with your variable c char.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with your code. Check the words in the `wordList`. If at all there is any word that starts with the char you send, it definitely reports.

Comment: I'm making an acrostic poem generator for an English project, so the wordList contains values starting with every letter of the alphabet. The method gets called for each individual letter of a word, and ideally gives a value from wordList for each letter.

Comment: what date are you testing with??

Comment: I'm testing with any word that is input through a keyboard scanner. The data being used is being read from a .txt document. I know that the data and word are being read properly, but I can't find any errors in the code. The ArrayList just isn't adding any values for some reason

Comment: And use iterators rather than `get` in a loop whenever practical. Your `for` loop could be significantly simplified.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to return an `ArrayList` of words use the following:

```
public ArrayList<String> singlePhrase(char c, ArrayList<String> wordList) {
    ArrayList<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();
    for (int i = 0; i < wordList.size(); i++) {
        if (Character.toLowerCase(wordList.get(i).charAt(0)) == Character.toLowerCase(c)) {
            words.add(wordList.get(i));
        }
    }
    return words;
}
```

Note that it compares the **lowercase** version of both characters.

Comment: That's what the method was previously, but I changed it to show that the array is empty by the end of the method. When I run that, it return three empty ArrayLists like this : [ ], [ ], [ ]

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys for all the help, but the answer was way too simple. In the .txt file that was being parsed, all the strings began with uppercase letters. The test input was all lowercase, resulting in the '==' being false and the if() statement never being triggered.